# Choosing a Database

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, database-design

Right now we are using a MySQL version 5.1.72 database. It's not a cluster database but a regular one. 64-bit ("mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.72, for sun-solaris2.11 (x86_64) using readline 6.3") We are using dedicated servers, not a redundant cloud solution. I have experienced that the more customers we squeeze into our platform, the more problems we get with

```
2016-02-15 13:26:36,737 WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - <SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000>
2016-02-15 13:26:36,737 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - <Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction>
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.marin.core.server.model.TableName]
```

Could switching to another database help us? Or maybe just a cluster version of MySQL? Some tables have millions of rows in them. The largest table has a size of about 5 GB. It has a lot of indices.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that kind of problem is due to

- Inadequate indexing.  Often this is because of indexing single columns and failing to use "composite" indexes to better advantage.
- Bulky data leading to extra I/O (which is the slow part of any query).  This can be remedied by more careful picking of datatypes and/or normalizing.
- Inefficient queries -- there are certain constructs that are known to be inefficient, and can be reformulated to get great increase in performance.

Suggest you set `long_query_time=1` and turn on the slowlog.  Then wait a day and run `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest` to find out what is running long.  (Note: that particular timeout usually manifests itself as queries taking almost exactly 50 seconds.)

Then let's look at the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, fix them, and educate your users on how to avoid repeating the problem.

Comment: But if you have an autoincremented single column primary key, it will always have an index.

Comment: That index is useful only if you have that `id` for looking up.  If, instead, you need to fetch by `name`, the `id` is useless.

Comment: Many tables have a composite PK but a lot have an autoincremented single column PK. There are also others which have indices on single columns which are not part of the PK.

Comment: I need to see specifics in order to address you problem further.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, etc.